# How to find cognates (ie: words with the same etymology) in English and French?

Tags: anglais, étymologie, histoire, ressources, lexique

Many French and English words are related, though often not synonyms or "faux amis".

Are there some good lists of such cognates or some database/tool/website that makes it easy to track them down, preferably with some etymological context?

(Especially those that are not "faux amis"  or "vrais amis").

Examples:

- (f) Bonjour, jour, journal - (e) journey, journal.
- (f) Cheval - (e) Cavalry

Comment: You will have to work on etymologies. http://www.etymonline.com/ will give you the etymology of English words and whether they come from French. Wiktionary isn't too bad either.

Answer (score 2):

This PDF is quite nice : http://blogimages.bloggen.be/ivemontpellier3/attach/166241.pdf

The first 2 columns are the English word and its actual translation in French, while the 2 last columns are the "immediate translation" a French would do and the actual meaning in English.

For instance, *to arrive* means *to reach a destination*, while a French would think it means *arriver* (i.e. *to happen*).

Comment: Be careful, French verb *arriver* has many different meaning (*to happen*, *to succeed*, *to come*, ...)

Comment: @Fractaliste and *arriver* means "to arrive" as well. Actually it's the most common meaning of arriver!

Comment: It is a nice list, but it seems to only cover quite similar words, not related words spelled quite differently.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve disambiguation I personally use [linguee.com/.fr](http://www.linguee.com/) website.

It's not a translation website nether a dictionary, it's a **translation memory** based on other website translations. So there is no etymological or other grammatical information, but its aim is to provide a dozen of relatively reliable example to allow you to understand in which context your sentence can be used.